# Time.toMillis(boolean) does not factor in time zone

Tags: java, android

Consider the following code:

```
Time time1 = new Time("America/Los_Angeles"); // UTC -8
Time time2 = new Time("Pacific/Kiritimati");  // UTC +14

time1.setToNow();
time2.setToNow();

Log.d("timetest", "America/Los_Angeles: " + time1.toMillis(false));
Log.d("timetest", "Pacific/Kiritimati : " + time2.toMillis(false));
```

Here is the log that gets output:

```
08-03 07:27:50.687: D/timetest(28411): America/Los_Angeles: 1375540070000
08-03 07:27:50.687: D/timetest(28411): Pacific/Kiritimati : 1375540070000
```

As you can see, the millisecond values are identical, even though they're a full 22 hours apart due to time zones. This leads me to believe that `Time.toMillis(boolean)` is basing itself off of UTC, not the `Time`'s designated time zone. I need a way to get the milliseconds based off of the `Time`'s time zone. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

The number of elapsed milliseconds since epoch 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC is the same everywhere. It doesn't matter whether you are currently in Los Angeles or Kiritimati.

---

**EDIT**

The `toMillis` method will return the number of milliseconds since epoch. Epoch is 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Think about it this way. If person A was born in Los Angeles at epoch and person B was born in Kiritimati at epoch, then the age of person A would be `time1.toMillis()` and the current age of person B would be `time2.toMillis()`, right?

Even though in the UTC timezone it was midnight when they were born, in their respective timezones it wasn't midnight. This you can tell from their timezones being UTC-8 and UTC+14.

Now if `time1.toMillis() != time2.toMillis()` it would mean that one of the two people is older. It would mean he lived more milliseconds in his life. Of course this is not the case because as we said they were born at the same time. That's why **the output you are seeing is correct** and I don't believe you should try to change it.

Comment: Good to know, however this doesn't answer the question. I need the milliseconds from epoch 1 January 1970 00:00:00 [Time.timezone].

Comment: @InsanityOnABun What do you want that for? There is only one epoch in java which is 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC. This is used as a reference point to calculate the elapsed time. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time.

Comment: @InsanityOnABun See my edit. I tried to be a bit more clear in my answer to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Yeah, I understand all that. I've actually been up all night hacking away at this app and I'm not really thinking straight at this point, haha. I'm slowly starting to piece together something to do what I need, but it's completely different from anything regarding this question. I'll probably just flag it for deletion. Thanks for being patient with me, though.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using `Time.gmtoff` which contains the UTC offset in seconds.

```
Time time1 = new Time("America/Los_Angeles"); // UTC -8
Time time2 = new Time("Pacific/Kiritimati");  // UTC +14

time1.setToNow();
time2.setToNow();

Log.d("timetest", "America/Los_Angeles: " + (time1.toMillis(false) - (time1.gmtoff * 1000)));
Log.d("timetest", "Pacific/Kiritimati : " + (time2.toMillis(false) - (time2.gmtoff * 1000)));
```

Resulting log:

```
08-03 07:53:04.866: D/timetest(31414): America/Los_Angeles: 1375566784000
08-03 07:53:04.866: D/timetest(31414): Pacific/Kiritimati : 1375491184000
```

Comment: You should add the offset, not substract it. The time (long value) of Pacific/Kiritimati should be "bigger" than LA's value, since Kiritimati always see a new day first than anyone else in the world